# Sync Facebook on different Android devices to avoid getting duplicate notifications

Tags: android, facebook, synchronization

My wife has two Android tablets, a Nexus 2012 and a Dell Venue. If after using one tablet for a few days, she uses the other, then she gets a lot of Facebook notifications which she already got on the other tablet.

Is there any software which will keep the Facebook app on the those tablets in sync, so that any notification acknowledged on one doesn't appear on the other?